# Extract outlinelvl of docx in java

Tags: java, docx

I'm trying to extract `docx` in Java and I want to get `Lvl outline` to save to Database. My Document:

```
 1. List item

 1.1 AAAA
        Content of AAAA

    1.2 BBBB
        Content of BBBB
```

How can i get content of AAAA and content of BBBB?

Comment: Whether you try docx4j or POI, it boils down to iterating through the document contents, checking the outline level setting, and if set, gathering the contents and writing it.  Have a try and post your code :-)  The tricky bit is if the outline level is set in the style hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you  but I solved it already. convert DOCX -> HTML then i organize tree data from it and save to database. Its work good. Thank for your help :).